# Search an integer value in a json array of integers

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a `json array` of `integers` which I have already sorted. So now I want to search an **integer element** inside the `json array`.(The size of the `json array` varies depending upon the situation, but it only contains `integers` and nothing else). What is the best way to make an efficient search?

Comment: Assuming the array is sorted, and you know how to search, binary search is the most efficient.

Comment: Linear search, which is the first thing that came to my mind, but i just want to make an efficient search as the searching is done very often and performance of my app depends on it too.

Comment: @Rohit check out this site:   http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html

Comment: have you tried ? jsonArray.toString().contains("");

Comment: I can use the binary search, just for knowledge, does android/java provide something for searching? like we have Collections.sort(Arraylist<Integer>) for sorting a List of integer values.

Comment: @Rohit it appears so, however it is for a list[] implementation, more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 2):

You can do binary search of the array like:

1- Set min/max integer indexes to cover your whole float array

2- test the value in the middle of the range at index mid=(min+max/2) against the search value x

3- if x is lower than this value, set max to mid, else set min to mid

4- repeat (2-4) until you have found the correct value

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Friar Bob, I used binary search to make the search. I first converted the json array into a List variable named selectedCatIds and used the below method to return true if the element is found else false. Thanks all for the help. Binary search indeed does the work efficiently.

```
 private boolean searchInSelectedIdsList(int storeCatId){
    int notFound = -1;
    int low=0,high=selectedCatIds.size()-1,mid =(low+high)/2;
    while(low<=high &&  selectedCatIds.get(mid)!=storeCatId){
        if(selectedCatIds.get(mid)<storeCatId)
            low = mid+1;
        else
            high = mid-1;
        mid = (low+high)/2;
    }
    if(low>high)
        mid=notFound;
    return (mid>=0);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Ensure that when you add new items that they get put in the sorted order as well, otherwise you will have some overhead if you have to resort every time you want to access or search for the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = "{\"array\":[\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"]}";

var searchInt= int value;


for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){

  if (obj[i].code == searchInt){

    // obj[i].name is the matched result
  }
}
```

Comment: If I am correct then this is a linear search, i want to go for a better search algo. Though i found uptil now that binary search will do good.

Comment: how can you be sure he's using javascript? This is an android question and most likely java or c/c++ related...

Comment: because in this code we are traversing the complete array by looking at each element progressively.. which is after all linear search.

Comment: @inner Since there is no language tag given on the question, and it's about json, showing logic in JS is fine. In the worst case it will be understandable by anyone who knows Java or C/C++ or is sufficiently able to read pseudo code. **But** Bikash you should add some explanations. Just posting code is not good style here.